# How to call ajax in login form multi user

Tags: php, json, ajax

i have try ajax success and error. but its not working on my login form. but its work on my insert, update or delete php.

here my ajax code :

```
$('#login').submit(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'resto_proses_login.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function(status) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("error");
            }
        })
        return false;
    });
```

and this is my resto_proses_login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connect.php';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb WHERE user='$_POST[user]' AND pass='$_POST[pass]'");

if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 1)
    {   
        $return_arr=array();
        $row_array['status']='sukses';
        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
        echo json_encode($return_arr);

        $data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $_SESSION['access']=$data['access'];
        $_SESSION['nama']=$data['nama'];

}   if($_SESSION['access']== "ADMIN" )  {  header('location: admin/');    
}   elseif ($_SESSION['access']== "KASIR") {  header('location: kasir/');
}   elseif ($_SESSION['access']== "DAPUR") {  header('location: dapur/');
}   elseif ($_SESSION['access']== "PELAYAN") {  header('location: pelayan/');
}   else { echo "failed"; }
?>
```

if im not use ajax, this process have error with code. that error will show number line : undefined index: access. if it success. no error showing.
my question is if use ajax. it just show `alert("error");` although I input the correct data

Comment: The URL should be a string `'resto_proses_login.php'`

Comment: @GeorgeQ is right, try changing your url and see if it works.

Comment: yeah,, still not work